# SharePoint Online - Lookup column to other site collection data

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

In SharePoint Online, there are 2 sites - A & B.

**Site A** has a list called *Countries*.

In **Site B**, I have a new list called *Clients*.

I want to add a column called *Country* in *Clients* of **Site B**. This column will have a lookup to the *Countries* defined in **Site A**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible using straight forward way. Check if it is possible via "Content type hub".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to create a lookup column between two site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in SharePoint. But there is a 3-rd party tool that allows you to link lists from different sites - [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/). Its [Lookup control](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms-sp/how-to/csl.html) creates a regular text field for storing data from a related list and renders it as regular lookup column with the help of built-in field customizer.